# Посоветуйте плагин wordpress или вариант решения задачи

Tags: wordpress, плагин

Я новичок в WordPress. Переношу сайт с самописа. Нужно реализовать следующий функционал.

В любой части текста записей-тренировок вставить записи-упражнения таким образом, чтобы подгружать их названия с url, несколько фото и произвольное поле, которое заполняется вручную для каждой такой записи.

Пример части страницы на самописе - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я это вижу как шорткод, но очень важно чтобы выбор записи-упражнения производился из выпадающего списка по названию - так, пример с самописа [image: введите сюда описание изображения], а не по ID как во многих шорткодах, т.к. перенос существующих и создание новых записей-тренировок займёт колоссальное кол-во времени.

Возможно, кто-то сталкивался с похожей задачей. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, варианты решения.

Comment: Текст я вам поправил, но ссылка не работает. Ниже вашего вопроса есть текст-кнопка "править". Используйте её для правки ссылки. А лучше не ссылку на сайт, а картинку вставьте прямо в вопрос.

Comment: Код где? и что это за бешеные ссылки? да и вообще зачем вам вордпресс... Если самопис написан квалифицированным программистом, не вижу смысла менять на вордпресс, о котором все, все знают...

Comment: Лично я ничего не понял. Что нужно-то реализовать?

Comment: @SeVlad я тоже ничего не понял. Надеюсь, прояснится, когда автор поправит вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, подправила вопрос

Comment: По поводу самописа. Делал знакомый, не квалифицированный специалист. Сайт с костылями и кривой, но у него функционал местами хорошо продуманный. Кто то другой с кодом будет долго/дорого разбираться чтоб что то доделать, а к разрабу этого сайта обращаться нет желания и возможности. Проще перенести на cms, по которой много инфы и проще поддерживать, дорабатывать.

Comment: Ммм... Итак, что у нас есть? Некая запись типа Тренировки, в которые нужно вставить сколько угодно записей типа Упражнения. Изучите документацию как создавать произвольные типы постов и произвольные поля, в этом вам поможет плагин MetaBox.

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, нужен выбор записи-упражнения в админке, при создании записи-тренировки. Чтобы это было наглядно, я не вижу другого способа, кроме как использование визуального редактора типа Visual Composer. Но у него в базовом составе нет такого блока для вставки другой записи. Попробуйте вот это решение: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.jonahcoyote.com/use-custom-post-widget-visual-composer/amp/#ampshare=https://www.jonahcoyote.com/use-custom-post-widget-visual-composer/

Comment: Да, всё верно про выбор. Спасибо, ознакомлюсь.

Comment: Изучить произвольные типы контента, произвольные таксономии, произвольные поля. Дело не столько в том КАК вывести, сколько в создании нужной структуры данных. Задача в целом не особо сложная, но не для новичка в ВП.

Comment: Еще вопрос в том, что нужно выводить это в середине статьи и чтобы была возможность объединять записи типа Упражнения во вкладки - http://prntscr.com/irhmp3. Я это не указала в вопросе, т.к. рассчитывала что мне посоветуют шорткод, а направили в русло с которым я еще не знакома.